Are there predefined rules/schema in Memgraph?
Is it possible that I can have a predefined rules/schema in Memgraph?
Like when ever the node would get created, on basis of its property it would get automatically connected to the resources which the properties are matching or the rule is defined.

Memgraph doesn't support a predefined schema, but if I understood it correctly, a similar thing could be achieved with triggers, so feel free to try it. Here is one example:
CREATE TRIGGER trigger ON --> CREATE BEFORE COMMIT
EXECUTE CALL {
MATCH (n1:Node1), (n2:Node2)
WHERE n1.prop1 = n2.prop1
CREATE (n1)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(n2)
}
RETURN *;

